# Pandas: groupby and get median value by feature and index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, median, indices

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':list('abcde'),'latitude': [38.470628, 38.554155, 38.66937, 34.119578, 36.292307],'longitude': [-121.404586, -121.502341, -121.695325, -117.413791, -119.804074],
 'flag': [1,1,1,1,0], 'idx': [[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[3],[4]], 'saleprice_usd_per_sqf': [200, 300, 700, 350, 50]})


   id    latitude     longitude   flag     idx     saleprice  result     
0   a   38.470628   -121.404586    1    [0, 1, 2]   200         300
1   b   38.554155   -121.502341    1    [0, 1, 2]   300         300
2   c   38.669370   -121.695325    1    [0, 1, 2]   700         300
3   d   34.119578   -117.413791    1    [3]         350         350
4   e   36.292307   -119.804074    0    [4]          50          50
```

Pls help to calculate median of saleprice (result as example) for each id, grouped by flag through indices idx.

Comment: Question does not make sense to me. Group by id, ok, and then "by flag through indices idx"? What's that supposed to mean? Please include the desired output for your sample dataframe and explain how that output is reached.

Comment: added to question

Comment: I still don't understand what "grouped by flag through indices idx" means. Please try to explain in more detail.

Comment: @timgeb I imagine grouped by `idx`, but I agree this is poorly phrased

Comment: @Dima if you expect a clear answer, please provide a breakdown of the calculation, how do you get 300 for instance? How is `flag` involved?

Comment: The idx marks objects that are located within a radius of, for example, 2 miles. And the flag, for example, the presence or absence of a fireplace. I need to calculate the median price for houses in the same cluster idx grouped for houses with and without fireplaces

Comment: ok, so just add another grouping criterion to my answer (updated)

Answer (score 0):

Your grouping logic is unclear, but assuming you want the median per group of `idx`:

```
df['result'] = (df['saleprice_usd_per_sqf']
                .groupby([df['idx'].apply(tuple), df['flag']])
                .transform('median')
               )
```

*NB. if order in `idx` doesn't matter, use `frozenset` in place of `tuple`*
output:

```
  id   latitude   longitude  flag        idx  saleprice_usd_per_sqf  result
0  a  38.470628 -121.404586     1  [0, 1, 2]                    200   300.0
1  b  38.554155 -121.502341     1  [0, 1, 2]                    300   300.0
2  c  38.669370 -121.695325     1  [0, 1, 2]                    700   300.0
3  d  34.119578 -117.413791     1        [3]                    350   350.0
4  e  36.292307 -119.804074     0        [4]                     50    50.0
```

Comment: @timgeb Oops you're right, I had misread, but anyway there is definitely ambiguity all over the question ;)